# Fragment with DatePickerDialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, dialog

I have a fragment in which I have to select a date. for this purpose, I created the fragment data (DatePicker Dialog). I would like to know why the following methods are deprecated:
in the FragmentAddPaziente: onActivityResult and setTargetFragment;
in the FragmentData: getTargetFragment and onActivityResult.

FragmentAggiungiPaziente

```
EditText nomePaz, cognomePaz, dataPaz, mailPaz, telefonoPaz;
String selectedDate;
Button aggiungiPaz;
DBHelper dbPaz;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1; // Codice per identificare il risultato

View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aggiungi_paziente, container, false);

    nomePaz = view.findViewById(R.id.nomePazNew);
    cognomePaz = view.findViewById(R.id.cognomePazNew);

    final FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
    dataPaz = view.findViewById(R.id.dataPazNew);

    dataPaz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Istanzio un oggetto di tipo FragmentData
            FragmentData newFragment = new FragmentData();
            //Setto questo nuovo fragment in modo da poter ricevere il risultato, specificando il codice REQUEST_CODE
            //setTargetFragment stabilisce la relazione tre due fragment: permette al fragment chiamato (in questo
            //caso, il FragmentData), di sapere dove inviare il risultato
            newFragment.setTargetFragment(FragmentAggiungiPaziente.this, REQUEST_CODE);
            newFragment.show(fm, "datePicker");
        }

    });

    mailPaz = view.findViewById(R.id.mailPazNew);
    telefonoPaz = view.findViewById(R.id.telefonoPazNew);
    dbPaz = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    //
    aggiungiPaz = view.findViewById(R.id.aggiungiPazBtn);
    aggiungiPaz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nome = nomePaz.getText().toString();
            String cognome = cognomePaz.getText().toString();
            String data = dataPaz.getText().toString();
            String mail = mailPaz.getText().toString();
            String telefono = telefonoPaz.getText().toString();
            Sessione sessione = new Sessione(getActivity());
            String mail_medico = sessione.getSessione();

            if (nome.equals("") || cognome.equals("") || data.equals("") || mail.equals("") || telefono.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserisci tutti i campi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                boolean controlloPaz = dbPaz.controlloPaziente(mail_medico,nome,cognome,data,mail,telefono);
                if (controlloPaz==true){
                    boolean inserisci = dbPaz.inserisciPaziente(mail_medico, nome,cognome, data,mail,telefono);
                    if(inserisci==true){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Paziente inserito con successo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayoutMain,new FragmentListaPazienti()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserimento fallito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Paziente già inserito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
//Permette di ricevere il dato dal FragmentData, specificando il codice della richiesta e il codice del risultato
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Controllo sui codici
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Prelevo il dato dalla stringa
        selectedDate = data.getStringExtra("selectedDate");
        // Setto il valore dell'editText con il valore appena prelevato
        dataPaz.setText(selectedDate);
    }
}
```

FragmentData

public class FragmentData extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    // i:anno, i1:mese, i2:giorno
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, i);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, i1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i2);
    String selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ITALIAN).format(c.getTime());

    // Invio la data al fragment che ha chiamato questo fragment
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
            getTargetRequestCode(),
            Activity.RESULT_OK,
            new Intent().putExtra("selectedDate", selectedDate)
    );


}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int anno = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mese = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int giorno = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), FragmentData.this, anno, mese, giorno);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In google Fragment documentation, [getTargetFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getTargetFragment()) is deprecated.

This method is deprecated.
Instead of using a target fragment to pass results, use setFragmentResult to deliver results to FragmentResultListener instances registered by other fragments via setFragmentResultListener.

so in Fragment you should do:

```
childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
   "KEY",
   this, 
   { _, result -> [... do something here] }
)

dialog.show(childFragmentManager, TAG)
```

and in DialogFragment

```
getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("KEY", bundle);
```